# samba and firewall, how to setup right?

Tags: samba

I have a win10 machine and after the wannacry thing, I decided to block 445, 135-139 ports and disable samba v1 on it.
But now I need to access files on it from my macbook. How should I proceed?
Do I need to enable samba v2 on win10? Do I have to (must) unblock the ports to samba v2/v3 work?
There is any other way?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Neither of those sites. It should be https://serverfault.com/

Comment: my bad. thank you.